# Dynamically change grind size in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ng-grid

In my application, I have to delete few row from ag-grid based on user input , I am using something like below

```
  rowsToDelete:RowDataTransaction = {remove: userSelectedRows};
  this.gridOptions.api.updateDataRow(rowsToDelete);
```

After execution of above code grid removes rows part of Array "userSelectedRows", However if i try to get the size of grid using

```
  let size =this.gridOptions.rowData.lenght,
```

Still i am getting actual size.

So how can i get update grid size after rows are deleted?

Apologies i couldn't paste actual code here due to my firm policy.

Comment: You can try to use counter for rows. Initially you must set it to length of your data and when rows deleted decrease it based on userSelectedRows length.

Comment: Can you use a table in the place of grid?